# Working with rdd

Tags: python, apache-spark

I have a rdd

```
[u'1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2013,52,0,4,1,0',
 u'1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,2012,49,1,1,0,1',
 u'1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,2012,49,1,1,0,1',
 u'0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,2014,45,0,0,1,0']
```

With this code

```
rdd = rdd.groupBy(lambda x: x.split(",")[9])
new_rdds = [sc.parallelize(x[1]) for x in rdd.collect()]

for x in new_rdds:
    print x.collect()
```

I got

```
 [u'1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2013,52,0,4,1,0'],
 [u'1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,2012,49,1,1,0,1',
  u'1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,2012,49,1,1,0,1']
 [ u'0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,2014,45,0,0,1,0']
```

Is there a way to get only a specific rdd , for example where x[9]=2014

so I can get

```
[u'0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,2014,45,0,0,1,0']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter the input rdd e.g. `rdd.filter(lambda x: x.split(",")[9] == 2014)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter() to select specific lines.

With your starting rdd:

```
rdd = rdd.filter(lambda line: line.split(",")[9] == 2014)
```